# Installing and using HDF5 for Eclipse on Mac OSx

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, hdfs, hdf5

I am trying to install and use the HDF5 libraires in eclipse in order to read and manipulate a dataset for my Big Data class.

I followed the instructions from the following website : http://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/release/downloadsrc.html

At the end of the installation, after the command

`ctest -S HDFJAVAMacCMake.cmake -C Release -V -O hdf-java.log`

I get the following message :

```
100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 313

Total Test time (real) =  39.85 sec
[ERROR_MESSAGE] 
Error in read script: /Users/fg/Downloads/build/HDFJAVAMacCMake.cmake
```

I don't understand why I get the `Error in read script` after every test passed.

Was the installation successful or not ? If yes, how do I manage to link the hdf5 libraries into my eclipse project ?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to link and use the library in Eclipse. For those with the same problem, here is what I did.

After building the HDF-java software with cmake (as described in the link I provided), I still get the error message

```
[ERROR_MESSAGE] 
Error in read script: /Users/fg/Downloads/build/HDFJAVAMacCMake.cmake
```

But everything has been compiled successfully (I still don't know why I get this message though).

Then, the following dmg appears in the build directory `HDFView-2.10.1-Darwin.dmg` (for version 2.10.1 of course). You need open it and  drag it to your application folder. This "app" (right click, Show Package Content) contains the java libraries for HDF4 and HDF5, as well as the native librairies (`.dylib` for mac osx).

The paths are the following,
JARs files : `/Applications/HDFView.app/Contents/Java`
Native libs: `/Applications/HDFView.app/Contents/Resources/lib`

At this point, you can open Eclipse and go to the "Build Path Configuration" of your project and  provide both the JARs and the native lib **path**.

Under the **Libraries** tab, you have to provide all the JARs contained in the first path I mentioned above. Then, go to the **Source** tab and you should see **Native library location** under your project. Simply give the second path I mentioned above.

Now you should be able to use the HDF libraries and compile your project without exception.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that the native libs must be loaded only ONCE, or else you will get an Exception (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError). In other words, either you load the libs as explained above, either you provide the path as VM Argument when running your Java app (-Djava.library.path=%PATH_TO_THE_NATIVES%)